# How do I properly refetch and cache updated data in React Apollo 2.0?

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I've been trying to update my cache with the newest data refetched from my server, but for some reason all my old data keeps getting persisted until I restart my server or do something like client.resetStore().

When I first start my app, it stores an email in the client cache. Then using this cached email, it gets passed into a server side query to fetch data about the user. I then access that data through props and render my UI into something like "Welcome Ken.". However ... if I go into my database and change the name to say .. "Nek" manually, then hit the refresh button, I expected a "Welcome Nek." but instead, it's still "Ken". I can see that on my server side the correct data was retrieved from the DB, but when I look inside my cache using Apollo devtools, I can see that it's still the previous data and hasn't been updated with the newly fetched data.

At the bottom I included a log for after I hand changed the name inside of the DB. The only thing I changed is the "first_name" field from "Ken" to "Nek" that's all.

Aside from trying to use refetch(), refetchQueries, polling... I've also tried executing another mutation just to see if it will update after a re-render, but no luck on that either.

After some debugging, I found that my data only updates after I restart my node server, this makes me wonder if I perhaps did something incorrectly in my setup configs? Because on my client-side even if I clear my caches and do a hard refresh, or close my tab/browser, it still grabs my old data. I'm not using the persist link either.

**ApolloConfig.js**

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const stateLink = withClientState({ cache, resolvers, defaults, typeDefs });

const authLink = setContext((request, prevContext) => ({
  headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') || '' }
}));

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: `${gqlUrl}graphql`
});

const link = ApolloLink.from([stateLink, authLink.concat(httpLink)]);
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
  connectToDevTools: true
});
```

**Server-Side index.js**

```
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  bodyParser.json(),
  graphqlAuthentication,
  graphqlExpress({
    schema,
    context: { loaders: createLoaders() }
  })
);

app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: '/graphql' }));
```

**DashboardContainer.js**
*The refetch function here was just used for testing on whether or not my props would update (when the function is invoked, I can indeed see the correctly fetched data/request on my server-side)*

```
class DashboardContainer extends Component {

  refetch = () => {
    this.props.data.refetch();
    this.props.setUser({ variables: { user: this.props.data.user } });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Dashboard {...this.props} />
        <button onClick={this.refetch}>Refresh</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

DashboardContainer.propTypes = {};

const query = gql`
  query QUERY_USER_EMAIL($email: String!) {
    user(email: $email) {
      id
      email
      bcomm_client_id
      first_name
      last_name
      __typename
    }
  }
`;
export default compose(
  graphql(QUERY_GET_USER_EMAIL),
  graphql(query, {
    options: props => ({
      variables: { email: props.data.email },
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
    })
  }),
  graphql(MUTATION_UPDATE_USER, { name: 'setUser' })
)(DashboardContainer);
```

**Server-Side Schema.js**

```
 type User {
        id: ID!
        email: String
        last_login: String
        first_name: String
        last_name: String
        roles: String
        is_active: Boolean
        bcomm_client_id: ID
        bcomm_access_token: String
    }

    type Query {
        user(email: String!): User!
    }
```

**Client-Side Queries.js**

```
export const QUERY_GET_USER_EMAIL = gql`
  {
    email @client
  }
`;
```

**Server-Side Log**

```
------- USER -------
TextRow {
  id: 15,
  last_login: null,
  first_name: 'NEK',
  last_name: 'WOW',
  roles: 'Admin',
  is_active: 1,
  email: 'hi@hi.com',
  bcomm_client_id: null,
  bcomm_access_token: null }
-------      Request (POST)     -------
{ host: 'localhost:8081',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '244',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  accept: '*/*',
  origin: 'https://localhost:3000',
  authorization: '',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8' }
{ operationName: 'QUERY_USER_EMAIL',
  variables: { email: 'hi@hi.com' },
  query: 'query QUERY_USER_EMAIL($email: String!) {\n  user(email: $email) {\n    id\n    email\n    bcomm_client_id\n    first_name\n    last_name\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n' }
```

**client.Store console.log**

```
ROOT_QUERY:
email: "hi@hi.com"
user: {type: "id", id: "User:15", generated: false}
user({"email":"hi@hi.com"}): {type: "id", id: "User:15", generated: false}  __typename: "AuthDefaults"
__proto__: Object
User:15:
    bcomm_client_id: null
    email: "hi@hi.com"
    first_name: "KEN"
    id: "15"
    last_name:"WOW"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is still wondering what the heck happened here. I found out that it was due to the DataLoaders that I was using for GraphQL. I didn't have the correct hooks setup properly so the DataLoaders kept sending me the cached data because it wasn't aware of any of the changes that were happening in my DB. This explained why I only saw the correct updates after restarting my server, cause in doing so it emptied out the cached data.